# How to disallow bulk urls from robots.txt?

Tags: seo, robots.txt

I built a dynamic sitemap generator on my platform. By mistake I generated some 300+ wrong url along with the right ones. And they have been there for couple weeks now. Recently I found out this mistake. Some of those wrong urls are already indexed by google. I spoke with one SEO specialist and he told me to follow two steps:

1. Add all of those wrong url to **Remove Url** on web masters.
2. Next `Disallow` all those url from robots.txt.

I did the first step.
I don't know how to do the second step. I have some 300+ urls like bellow:

```
https://example.com/equip?category_id=semi-automatic
https://example.com/equip?category_id=automatic
https://example.com/equip?category_id=other
```

Currently I cant implement `404` on these urls from coding side. Its quiet complicated now. So could any body please tell me how can I disallow these from robots.txt ??

Comment: Do you need to allow all category_ids or are there some that still need to be crawled and indexed?

Comment: There are some that needs to be crawled

Answer (score 1):

You have to define first the engines you want them to skip your pages with **user-agent** (use * for all engines). Then  you can specify the list of relative urls you want to remove. Each element preceded by **Disallow:**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /equip?category_id=semi-automatic
Disallow: /equip?category_id=automatic
Disallow: /equip?category_id=other
```